# Menu with active LI

Tags: css, menu, html-lists

Maybe fresh eyes can see where i am going wrong with this but i want the active menu item to have a different style...

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#menu ul {list-style-type: none;height: 40px;float: left;margin-top: 43px;margin-left:-32px;}
#menu li {
float: left;
}
#menu li #active {
background: url(../images/menu-bg-hover.png) no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
}
#menu li a {
background: url(../images/menu-bg.png) no-repeat;
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 40px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center; 
padding-top: 10px;
color:#424242;
font-family: "Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just fix the style like this:

```
#menu li#active {
  background: url(../images/menu-bg-hover.png) no-repeat;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

You had written it as `#menu li #active` rather than `#menu li#active`.

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS to `#menu li#active a` and place it below `#menu li a`. This will ensure that the styling overrides the default styles, in this case the background image and text color.

`#menu li #active` forces the browser to locate a child element with the id `active` under `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
#menu li #active {
background: url(../images/menu-bg-hover.png) no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

ADD

```
#menu #active a{
background: url(../images/menu-bg-hover.png) no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
}
```